# Not overengineered or underengineered

Tags: word-choice

I'm looking for a word to describe a solution that is simple, fast to develop and fulfills its intended purpose. The word "adequate" is not quite what I'm after. The shade of meaning I want to impart is that the solution is good quality, and not over- or underengineered. I suppose I could say "well engineered".

Can anyone suggest an alternative?

I thought of "optimal" but this implies a kind of exactness that I don't want to portray. I want to suggest there's a range of possible solutions that could work and not be considered over- or underengineering. For example, to meet some need we could put together a spreadsheet or a little database and both of these would be acceptable solutions, neither is "optimal". Whereas a custom built application might be overengineering and a manual system might be underengineering.

I'm not sure that "well engineered" really captures what I want to say.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Elegant** is widely used in science and mathematics to describe a theory which exactly and economically describes the data. It is also used in engineering in the sense desired.

Comment: Definitely. I didn't see this question until your answer pushed it back up the list, but I immediately thought, "they should use *elegant*".

Comment: Elegant sounds fancy and a little over engineered to me.

Comment: I like this answer because it is the best description both in casual conversation and in industry jargon. The listener will know roughly what you meant--or exactly what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Reasonable, practical, sensible, level-headed? Well-designed? A solution might also be down-to-earth, functional, pragmatic or even commonsensical.

(these probably fit less, but you might find them useful anyway: suitable, appropriate, reasonably engineered, just right)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen *appropriate* used as a marketing term for this idea, as in an *appropriate solution* or *appropriate technology*.

Personally I like *right-sized* but it might not be as understandable to an audience.

Answer (score 0):

**Goldilocks engineered**. ;-)

What's wrong with just saying that the result is "*simple, fast to develop and fulfills its intended purpose*", as you so eloquently put it?

That's a thousand times better than any label you could come up with that would cover that, IMO.  Why be vague when you can say just what you mean?  Besides, what you claim to want to express is a message about the **result**.  It says **nothing** about the process (the "engineering") used to produce the result.  So why bring engineering into it?

**As always:** Decide first what your **message** is, as clearly as possible. Worry about the wording to best convey your message to your audience only after you know what your message is.  IOW, get the logic & content right first, and deal with the form second.

Answer (score 0):

"The engineering work that goes into our solutions is tailored to {match / fit} their intended purpose".

Answer (score 0):

*Rationally* engineered sounds good to me and you could use it.  I think a better term to use would be to say that it is **logically** engineered.

Answer (score 0):

Good enough. It means you've met all the requirements, probably in the most straightforward way possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to be concise, I would suggest...

aptly/appropriately/befittingly engineered